# Show location of excepted error

Tags: python

I have some code that is throwing this error when a read fails:
object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()

and i want to find which line in the code is causing this. This is printed in an except statement:

```
except Exception, err:
    print "Unable to read data"
    print err
```

Comment: @Martijn Peters `traceback` is also available in Python2.

Comment: Of course it is; that's just the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module you can do:

```
try:
    # your code here
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```